# Can a company charge a fee for erasure under GDPR?

Tags: european-union, gdpr

Suppose a company has a mailing list to reach out to potential customers. They send both physical and electronic mail. One EU-based potential customer does not want to receive mail anymore and requests their data to be erased under GDPR. Can this company charge a fee for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Art. 17 GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-17-gdpr/) contains the Right to erasure (‘right to be forgotten’).

[Art. 12(5) GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-12-gdpr/) contains:

> 5. Information provided under Articles 13 and 14 and any communication and any actions taken under **Articles 15 to 22** and 34 shall be provided **free of charge**. Where requests from a data subject are manifestly unfounded or excessive, in particular because of their repetitive character, the controller may either:
>
>    (a) charge a reasonable fee taking into account the administrative costs of providing the information or communication or taking the action requested;
>
>    or
>
>    (b) refuse to act on the request.
>
>    The controller shall bear the burden of demonstrating the manifestly unfounded or excessive character of the request.

So it is not possible to charge a fee for this.

Regarding electronic mail, also take a look at Article 13(1,2) of [Directive 2002/58/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32002L0058)

> Article 13
>
> Unsolicited communications
>
> 1. The use of automated calling systems without human intervention (automatic calling machines), facsimile machines (fax) or electronic
>      mail for the purposes of direct marketing may only be allowed in
>      respect of subscribers who have given their prior consent.
> 2. Notwithstanding paragraph 1, where a natural or legal person obtains from its customers their electronic contact details for
>      electronic mail, in the context of the sale of a product or a service,
>      in accordance with Directive 95/46/EC, the same natural or legal
>      person may use these electronic contact details for direct marketing
>      of its own similar products or services provided that customers
>      clearly and distinctly are given the opportunity to object, 
>      **free of charge** and in an easy manner, to such use of electronic contact
>      details when they are collected and on the occasion of each message in
>      case the customer has not initially refused such use.

Note that this is a [Directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directive_(European_Union)), so it is not directly binding, but each EU member state has created it's own laws containing this.

[Article 95 GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-95-gdpr/) explicitly specifies it does not change any obligations from Directive 2002/58/EC.

So sending electronic mail to potential customers who have not given consent is unlawful because of paragraph 1. For existing customers paragraph 2 applies, removing must be free of charge.

Comment: in fact, GDPR requires such data to be removed unless consent has been explicitly given to retain it, and within a set timeframe when the data is no longer relevant (e.g. when a customer closes his account or an employee leaves your employment)